# Who calls fragment lifecycle methods (onCreate, onCreteView etc.) explicitly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I looked at the source code of fragment (v4) *http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#Fragment* but i cannot figure out who is calling lifecycle methods? who is standing behind that? some object or method must explictly call onCreate, onCreatView etc...

Comment: try Thread.dumpStack()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments share their lifecycle with their parent activity, which calls the lifecycle methods **implicitly**.

You can find the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-0/android/app/Activity.java), with methods like `dispatchActivityCreated`, `dispatchDestroy`, etc.